# Invalid SQL error on ObjectContext Query() -> Execute()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I am trying to update a table from inside my overridden SaveChanges().

**This query:**

```
UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate='5/19/2014 10:17:50 AM' WHERE Id=21
```

**Getting this error**

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'NewClub', line 1, column 8.
```

Obviously, I cannot use straight SQL here because the SQL is valid. What should the query look like or am I missing something else?

Thanks

```
     ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

     List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList =
           ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added
                                                      | EntityState.Unchanged
                                                      | EntityState.Modified
                                                      | EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

     foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
     {

            if (newClubPrimaryKeyId > 0)
            {
                string q = @"UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate='" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id=@id";
                ObjectQuery<NewClub> newClubQuery = ctx.CreateQuery<NewClub>(q, new ObjectParameter("id",newClubPrimaryKeyId));
                newClubQuery.Execute(MergeOption.PreserveChanges);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of LastActivityDate in your database?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the query execution statement:

```
            if (newClubPrimaryKeyId > 0)
            {
                string q = @"UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate='" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id="+newClubPrimaryKeyId;


                using (var context = new ReportingContext())
                {
                     var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(q);
                }


            }
```